How to cast from PostGres time to ADF time?
I am setting up an Azure Data Factory that links to a Postgres SQL server that is hosted elsewhere. Several of our pipelines are failing to copy data from their source Postgres tables into their Azure SQL server sink tables. This problem appears to be because of a failing "time" conversion.
While I am able to validate that other tables that do not contain "time" columns are being brought in correctly by their respective pipelines, I am unable to even preview the source dataset for the tables that do contain "time" columns in Azure Data Factory. Attempting to do so returns the following error:
Error code
DEDICATED_DPERRORCODE0

Details
Can't cast database type time without time zone to NpgsqlInterval

The DEDICATED_DPERRORCODE0 link goes to a generic troubleshooting page and does not touch on time zones or casting errors.
It appears that ADF is unable to read the Postgres server's columns that have "Time" as the type, due to trying to cast them to an "Interval" type without a time zone. I do not control the Postgres server; however, I have validated that the server does have the "time(0)" type for the columns in question. I lack the knowledge to be able to verify that the columns have a time zone attached as specified in the postgres documentation.
In the Azure documentation for the postgresql connector, it specifies that when importing from postgres, source columns with type "time" will be mapped to a "timespan" interim service data type. This is then converted to "Time" for the destination type for my columns. In the pipeline, I can see that this is how Azure generates the mapping for those columns.
For reference, here is an example screenshot of a failing test-pipeline:

This is the same error that occurs when trying to preview the data from the source table.
If I am reading the error correctly, Azure is attempting to cast the Time columns to an interval type. Doing that appears to require a time zone it doesn't have and doesn't match the stated documentation (but maybe Azure's interim TimeSpan data type is secretly an interval?).
If I utilize the Query option in the source tab of the Copy Data pipeline, I am able to return results if I pass through a query that only select columns that would not require this conversion, such as:
SELECT [Id]
FROM public.table

This is currently how we are bypassing this error, however, doing it this way leaves out the data of those time columns.
There is potentially a query that would allow the pass through of the data as some non-erroring type, however, ideally, I'd like to resolve the root of the issue without writing custom SQL for each import dataset as we plan to add more tables and time columns in the future.
Altering the server would be somewhat difficult, but not necessarily impossible. Is there a way to specify a time zone in ADF that it can automatically use to make the mapping that postgres provides, or other method to successfully cast the postgres time columns into something ADF can use?

Why don't you use dataflow option to change data type of column?


Can't cast database type time without time zone to NpgsqlInterval

The above error will occur when trying to convert or cast between time type to Interval type which is not supported.  If you want to copy data from Azure PostgreSQL table which is having time type column to Azure SQL table, follow below approach:
Select the PostgreSQL table as source and select SQL sink as below:

Enable Auto create table as table option in sink as shown below:

Go to mapping click on import schemas then the time without time zone column will change to Time type column as shown below:

You will be able to preview the PostgreSQL table data as shown below:

The table will copy successfully without any error. Alternatively, you can use data flow to change the data type of column in Projection  tab of source as shown below:


You have accurately described the intended final state and the steps I have tried to take to get there. However, I am unable to replicate your results. Step 1 can be executed correctly. Step 2, however, I see the source data column display "TimeSpan" instead of "time without time zone" after importing the schema. I am still unable to preview data in the that tab as well. I will update my question with a screenshot.

Even though if the column type imported as "timespan", I am able to view the source datalike this. Could you please provide your sample data with types from Azure PostgreSQL db?

How interesting! The actual PostgreSQL server isn't hosted in Azure--it's being pulled in via a linked service and an integration runtime. I don't have full access to the server either, though I can manually pull data down with Excel's Powerquery ODBC connector.
As for the PostgreSQL Datasets in Azure, I'm unable to preview the ones that link to tables with the columns in question.
Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for--is there somewhere else or somehow else I should be looking?

This issue was fixed at the end of October.
If you are using AzureIR, please retry.
If you are using SHIR, please upgrade to version 5.46.90 and above

Hey @tsaiggo, thanks for the update! We are using AsureIR with auto update on. I am still unable to preview the full dataset coming from the external postgres server with the time columns in question, and the pipeline still fails to run on the full dataset.
Do you know if this fix is fully rolled out?
